# Insert Values into database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, insert

I have been using the following code to insert the values into the MySQL database. The code builds with no error message but as soon as I try to run the code it says:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Column 'name' cannot be null

Please tell me the error in my code.

Here is the insert function that i am using:

```
public int insert (int id, string name, string sname, int marks )
{
     string connection= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
       MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);


    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student_details(id,name,sname,marks) values(@id,@name, @sname, @marks)");

   // com.Connection = com;
   com.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    //com.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
    //com.Parameters.Add("@name", name);
    //com.Parameters.Add("@sname", sname);
    //com.Parameters.Add("@marks", marks);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", sname);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marks", marks);
   //// com.Parameters.a
    //com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int ret = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in this error message? You're obviously inserting null in the `name` column...

Comment: When you call your `insert` method, is your argument `name` null?

Answer (score 1):

Can you rewrite your method with arguments validation? This will give you a **+1** to your programming style. Plus you will know faster if the input does not follow an expected contract.

```
public int insert (int id, string name, string sname, int marks )
{
    if(name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    ...
}
```

Seems like you are passing a `name` parameter which is `null`.

Comment: no i am getting the value of the parameter name from other front end page..i have posted the code below.plss see that

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure name is not null? You don't validate your params.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am using the simple following front end function to insert the value of data fields into the dataaccess layer class which has the function Insert()... please see to to it where i am going wrong........

```
try
{
    DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
    int id = 23;
    string name = "mayank";
    string sname = "agarwal";
    int marks = 34;
    int a = dal.insert(id, name, sname, marks);
    LblUserName.Text = a.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
        throw;
}
```